# How to create a torch.utils.data.Dataset and import it into a torch.utils.data.DataLoader

Tags: python, torchvision

I would like to import data from a CSV file with `torch.utils.data.Dataset` so I can use `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` to deal with it. The data does not belong to torchvision and it's from my PC. It seems that there is no solution on Google. I will thank a lot if you can give me some advice.

Answer (score 2):

If you already have the csv file you can do this very easily with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
my_dataframe = pd.read_csv("path/to/file.csv")
```

With this you can now acess the data inside your csv file.
If you want to use the pytorch `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` you will also need a `torch.utils.data.Dataset`.

Depending on the type of Data you are using the Dataset can look very differently. If you are dealing with imagepath and labels inside the csv, have a look at this Dataset I once used for `torchvision.models.resnet50()` :

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset
from PIL import Image
from torchvision import models, transforms
import cv2

class createDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        self.dataframe = dataframe
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor()])

    def __len__(self):
        return self.dataframe.shape[0]
        
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        image = self.dataframe.iloc[index]["Name_of_imagepath_column"]
        image = cv2.imread(image)
        image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        image = Image.fromarray(image)    
        image = self.transform(image)
        label = self.dataframe.iloc[index]["Name_of_label_column"]
        return {"image": image , "targets": torch.tensor(label, dtype=torch.long)}
```

The label/targets are optional and were only necessary in my project.

Now you can pass your pandas dataframe to the Dataset class like so:

```
my_dataset = createDataset(dataframe = my_dataframe)
```

It is now possible to pass this Dataset to a `torch.utils.data.DataLoader` and create your Dataloader :

```
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

my_dataloader= DataLoader(dataset=my_dataset)
```

For more options for the Dataloader, like batchsize and shuffle, look up [Pytorch DataLoader docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html)